# Magento: Custom menu extension - CSS to center menu

Tags: css, magento, menu, center

I use [Custom Menu extension for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-menu.html) but can't find out how to change custommenu.css to get the menu centered. This is a piece of code for menu:

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <div id="custommenu">
    <div id="menu3" class="menu" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup3', 'menu3')" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, 'popup3');">
    <div id="popup3" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, 'popup3', 'menu3')" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup3', 'menu3')" style="z-index: 9999;">
    <div id="menu4" class="menu" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup4', 'menu4')" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, 'popup4');">
    <div id="popup4" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, 'popup4', 'menu4')" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup4', 'menu4')" style="display: none; top: 25px; left: 77px; z-index: 10000;">
... rest of code...
```

And this is what I tried in CSS - text-align for #custommenu + display:inline-block for div.menu (and some other options too) but can't get it working:

```
#custommenu {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    width: 918px;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;    
}
div.menu {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Could you give me some hints how to get the menu centered? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will solve your CSS problem but you have `<div>`s that are not closed off:

**Corrected HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-container">
<div id="custommenu">
    <div id="menu3" class="menu" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup3', 'menu3')" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, 'popup3');"></div>
    <div id="popup3" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, 'popup3', 'menu3')" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup3', 'menu3')" style="z-index: 9999;"></div>
    <div id="menu4" class="menu" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup4', 'menu4')" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, 'popup4');"></div>
    <div id="popup4" class="wp-custom-menu-popup" onmouseover="wpPopupOver(this, event, 'popup4', 'menu4')" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup4', 'menu4')" style="display: none; top: 25px; left: 77px; z-index: 10000;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you have no access to the CSS file to edit it, you could try wrapping the `<div class="nav-container">` in another `<div>`.

**Example:**

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div id="custommenu">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then referencing the CSS like this:

```
div.nav-wrapper div.nav-container div#custommenu {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    width: 918px;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;    
}
div.nav-wrapper div.nav-container div#custommenu div.menu {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this - the DIV is closed. "..." was supposed to mean that the code continues, but is not that important. I have an access to the CSS, but editing does not help. I tried your way and doesn't work.

Comment: Any change i could see a working version? I also meant the divs with onmouseover events, they are not being closed off too.

Comment: Still did not figure it out. Seems your solution is not working.